# How to Ensure Immediate Availability of Updated Documents in Solr Search Results without Using Sleep in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr

I'm working on a Ruby application that uses Solr for search. I have a method that updates a person's contact data after the base indexing has been done.

Here's the relevant part of my Person model:

```
def update_contact
  person = find_in_solr
  p person
  => nil # doc not available
  # ... other code ...
end

def update_contact_with_sleep
  sleep 2
  person = find_in_solr
  p person
  => SolrDoc # doc is available
  # ... other code ...
end

def find_in_solr
  # assume this searches solr with the person id
end
```

Is there any other way that I can ensure the document is present without using sleep or another waiting mechanism?

Comment: You might need to force a commit when you update Solr for the search to pick up the updated value. Take a look at the Explicit Commit section in the documentation: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/configuration-guide/commits-transaction-logs.html#explicit-commits